# How can we create a Radial Pie chart?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex-charting, flex-charts

How can we create a Radial-Pie-Chart in Flex?

Basically i am trying to create a stacked pie chart. 
What should i do to achieve this?

Can we show stacked column chart in a pie?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One data visualization API that can be used in Flex is Axiis:

http://www.axiis.org/examples.html

Take a look at this sample to see if this is close to what you are looking for:

http://www.axiis.org/examples/WedgeStackChartExample.html

Comment: i'm trying to create [http://www.digitalsurgeons.com/facebook-vs-twitter-infographic/] in flex.

Comment: You're going to have to create your own component for this utilizing the AS3 drawing API.